# C# Instance of Lists In Data Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've not been able to find an answer so am posting this. If this has already been answered then please point me in that direction.

I have a class model in MVC as below:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }      
    public List<LocationModel> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class LocationModel
{
    public int LocationID {get; set;}
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to populate the Locations list in my code but can't seem to get the code to create an instance of it properly.

I have a List of SearchModel as there are multiple items. This is populating fine by doing the following:

```
List<SearchModel> items = new List<SearchModel>();
```

and then looping through the following to populate the model.

```
SearchModel item = new SearchModel();
item.ActivityName = reader["ActivityName"].ToString();
item.Level = reader["LevelNames"].ToString();
item.Subject = reader["SubjectNames"].ToString();
item.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ActivityID"]);
items.Add(item);
```

How do I add the data to the Locations List in the SearchModel? This will contain multiple records also.

Comment: What does `reader["LocationNames"].ToString()` return?

Comment: Sorry @Aschratt , ignore that. It was when I returned a test of just a single record. I'll update the code.

Comment: I'm not getting your question. How do you think it is different to instantiate a `List<SearchModel>` vs. a `List<LocationModel>`? You seem to have every required knowledge 'in place'. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
item.Locations = new List<LocationModel>();
```

you can add some data in it

```
var myLocationModel = new LocationModel();
myLocationModel.Location = "Africa";
item.Locations.Add(myLocationModel);
```

Comment: Thats great, I was missing the line var myLocationModel = new LocationModel(); So obvious but still missed it. I was doing item.Locations l = new List<LocationModel>() which gave me problems.